# Sequence involving floor function - limit and bounds

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

My first time here, so please excuse any breaches of etiquette.

For a given  $p \in \mathbb N$  and irrational $\alpha$, let $\varepsilon_n=\alpha n-\lfloor \alpha n \rfloor,$ and $S_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{n} p^{-\varepsilon_i}$ (where $n=0 , 1, ...$).

1. I suspect that $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n=\frac{p-1}{p \ln p}$, but have no idea how to prove (or disprove) it. [Edit: Many thanks to Daniel Fischer for explaining this].
2. I'd like to find some well-behaved bounding functions for the sequence $\{ S_n \}$, i.e., relatively simple continuous functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(n) \le S_n \le g(n)$: I think $f(x)=\frac{p-1}{p \ln p}$ and $g(x)=f(x)+\frac {1}{x+1}$ will do, but I would like some suggestions for proving/disproving this (or functions that are a tighter fit).

Can anyone please help with part 2, or point me towards some basic resources that might shed light on it?

Comment: See [equidistributed sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence) and [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem). Your suspicion about the limit is correct. I'm not sure whether that helps you find bounding functions, however.

Comment: Thanks for the references - I'm going to have to think hard about them. I'm gratified that my suspicion is correct :) , but precisely why still eludes me at the moment...

Comment: The sequence $(\varepsilon_n)$ is equidistributed in $[0,1]$, so $S_n \to \int_0^1 p^{-t}\,dt$.

Comment: Ah, that's something i _can_ work out! Thanks!